# Find the $ \lim_{x \rightarrow \pm\infty}( (x^4+5x)^{\frac12} - (x^2 - 5x)^{\frac12} )$

Tags: calculus, limits

Here's my try:

I took $x^4$ common from first part and $x^2$ common from the second part, however I get (infinity - infinity) as a result which is an indeterminate form. I cannot figure out any other way to evaluate this limit. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiply by $$\frac{\sqrt{(x^4 + 5x)} + \sqrt{x^2 - 5x}}{\sqrt{(x^4 + 5x)} + \sqrt{x^2 - 5x}}$$

Then you'll have a difference of "squares" in the numerator: $(\sqrt a - \sqrt b)(\sqrt a + \sqrt b) = a-b$.

You should get the function $$\frac{x^4 + 5x - (x^2 - 5x)}{\sqrt{(x^4 + 5x)} + \sqrt{x^2 - 5x}}$$

The function is now "top heavy": the numerator is of degree $4$, the denominator degree $2$. If you divide numerator and denominator by $x^2 = \sqrt{x^4}$, you'll have a degree two polynomial in the numerator, and constants in the denominator.

Now, check what happens as $x\to +\infty$ and $x\to -\infty$.

Comment: Then it comes out to be positive infinity for both cases.
And plugging in some random large values for x in the given function , we get large answers (i.e nearing infinity) so indeed the solution is verified.
Thanks

Comment: Yes indeed. You're welcome.